# No Privlieges to create database in phpmyadmin Mamp

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, mamp

I am using bitnami provided "mampstack-7.1.15-0".

I am trying to run an existing laravel application which i developed in wamp stack. Now i try to login to the phpmyadmin and create the database manually required for the application to run.

But i get the "No privileges" text in the databases screen of phpmyadmin.

Seems to be a problem with phpmyadmin because with mysql CLI its working with the user.

I followed some of the solutions mentioned in other SO posts but could not get this working.

Best Regards,

Saurav